# Qual é a finalidade de Object.is?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Percebi que o Javascript agora tem o [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) e, segundo a documentação:

> `Object.is` determina se dois valores correspondem ao mesmo valor.

Sobre isso me surgiu algumas dúvidas:

- Por que `Object.is`, se eu posso comparar os valores com `==` ou `===`? Se há diferença entre essas formas, quais são elas?
- De alguma forma, `Object.is` tem alguma semelhança com o operador `instanceof`? Essa dúvida me surgiu, pois geralmente `is` costuma-se usar em algumas linguagens para verificar se determinado valor corresponde a determinado objeto.
- Que benefícios `Object.is` traz ao Javascript?

Comment: A quem interessar, na MDN há um artigo tratando disso: [Comparações de igualdade e uniformidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: Wallace, peço desculpas. Eu tinha feito a tradução como resposta e iria adequá-la para sanar suas dúvidas...

Comment: @AndréFilipe tudo bem. A gente só alertou mesmo, porque essa prática aqui no site resulta em remoção da resposta e, em casos mais graves, até punição por banimento. Foi bom a gente alertar.

Comment: Vale a pena dar uma olhada no meta: @AndréFilipe: [Sobre cópia de artigos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5430/sobre-c%C3%B3pias-de-artigos)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As diferenças em relação ao operador [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity), segundo [a documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is), são:

1. `Object.is` distingue `+0` de `-0`, mas `===` não distingue.
2. `Object.is` considera dois `NaN` como "iguais" (o equivalente a `isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)`).

Na especificação da linguagem (ES2015/ES2016 em diante) existem [quatro algoritmos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) que lidam com comparação de igualdade. Um equivale ao `==`, outro ao `===`, um terceiro ao `Object.is`, e o quarto é utilizado em alguns construtores e métodos específicos.

Isso não tem nenhuma relação com `instanceof`, nem com herança. Os algoritmos de equivalência não olham para isso, quando lidam com objetos só verificam se os dois são o mesmo objeto ou não. O benefício é poder distinguir +0 de -0 e talvez o açúcar sintático para comparar os `NaN`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, jovem.

Comment: Obrigado pelo "jovem" rs