# Object.is() e === - Qual a diferença?

Tags: javascript

Qual seria a diferença do construtor

> object.is()

para o operador

> ===

Sendo que ambos comparam se dois valores são o mesmo, a diferença seria só o tipo de descrição ao retornar?

Comment: [Pelo que li](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) as principais diferenças são: `(NaN === NaN) === false` e `Object.is(NaN, NaN) === true`, `(+0 === -0) === true` e `Object.is(-0, +0) === false`.

Comment: A pergunta não é duplicata [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338337/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-de-object-is) ? Apesar do titulo ser diferente a mesma questão é feita no texto : "Por que Object.is, se eu posso comparar os valores com == ou ===? Se há diferença entre essas formas, quais são elas?" e a resposta aborda precisamente esse pormenor